# HTML5 canvas drawImage with at an angle

Tags: javascript, html, drawimage

I am experimenting with animation in `<canvas>` and can't work out how to draw an image at an angle. The desired effect is a few images drawn as usual, with one image rotating slowly. (This image is not at the centre of the screen, if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You need to modify the transformation matrix before drawing the image that you want rotated.

Assume image points to an HTMLImageElement object.

```
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var width = image.width;
var height = image.height;

context.translate(x, y);
context.rotate(angleInRadians);
context.drawImage(image, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
context.rotate(-angleInRadians);
context.translate(-x, -y);
```

The x, y coordinates is the center of the image on the canvas.

Comment: instead of rotating/translating at the end, you could do a `context.save()` and `context.restore()` before and after you do the transformations and drawing.

Comment: While using save()/restore() may seem cleaner, it would be much more inefficient. The engine will have to store/restore all the context properties, not just the ones we're manipulating here. That matters in a sensitive code path.

Comment: For another example, see this (duplicate) question and answer: [Dial of a Gauge using HTML5 Canvas - Rotate About Arbitrary Point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649836/dial-of-a-gauge-using-html5-canvas-rotate-about-arbitrary-point/4650102#4650102).

Comment: @JakubWieczorek No, the engine could easily keep "dirty" flags on each context property and lazily save (and then restore) only the ones that get touched between the `save()` and the `restore()`. Hand-tuning this is premature optimization.

Comment: what are the performance implication for doing this for a game, ie every game object is animated and is an image?

Comment: -1 Using `translate()` and `rotate()` to restore the transformation matrix is very bad advice. This will _not_ reliably restore the matrix to its original value due to rounding of floating-point operations.

Comment: @JakubWieczorek Do you have measured performance of these two approaches? I'd be surprised if two method calls (where `rotate()` needs to call two trigonometric functions) is faster than copying the whole transformation matrix (48 bytes, if implemented as 6 64-bit-floating point numbers).

Answer (score 21):

It is interesting that the first solution worked for so many people, it didn't give the result I needed.
In the end I had to do this:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(positionX, positionY);
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.translate(-x,-y);
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
ctx.restore();
```

where `(positionX, positionY)` is the coordinates on the canvas that I want the image to be located at and `(x, y)` is the point on the image where I want the image to rotate.

Comment: I had to do `ctx.translate(positionX + x, positionY + y);`, then rotate, and then translate by `ctx.translate(-x,-y);`

Answer (score 15):

I have written a function (based on Jakub's answer) that allows user to paint an image in a X,Y position based on a custom rotation in a custom rotation point:

```
function rotateAndPaintImage ( context, image, angleInRad , positionX, positionY, axisX, axisY ) {
  context.translate( positionX, positionY );
  context.rotate( angleInRad );
  context.drawImage( image, -axisX, -axisY );
  context.rotate( -angleInRad );
  context.translate( -positionX, -positionY );
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180; 
ctx = document.getElementById("canvasDiv").getContext("2d");
var imgSprite = new Image();
imgSprite.src = "img/sprite.png";

// rotate 45º image "imgSprite", based on its rotation axis located at x=20,y=30 and draw it on context "ctx" of the canvas on coordinates x=200,y=100
rotateAndPaintImage ( ctx, imgSprite, 45*TO_RADIANS, 200, 100, 20, 30 );
```

Comment: -1 Using `translate()` and `rotate()` to restore the transformation matrix is very bad advice. This will _not_ reliably restore the matrix to its original value due to rounding of floating-point operations.